# Array is emptry after push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I have an object constructor named Course :

```
 function Course(points,grade,coursename) {
  this.points;
  this.grade;
  this.coursename;}
```

an empty array named Courses:

```
Courses = [];
```

I'm creating a new object named "t" (whose values are entered with a form):

```
t=new Course($("#coursename").val(),$("#grade").val(), $("#points").val() );
```

I'm trying to push the values to the array but the console.log shows that it's empty.

```
Courses.push(t);
console.log(Courses[0]);
```

Comment: The title appears to be simply untrue. The object may be "empty", `{}`, but the array is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the arguments to properties in your constructor:

```
function Course(points, grade, coursename) {
    this.points = points;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.coursename = coursename;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor should be like:

```
function Course(points,grade,coursename) {
   this.points = points;
   this.grade = grade;
   this.coursename = coursename;
}
```

You need to assign parameter to some atribute of your `Course` object in the constructor.

Comment: Returning `this` from constructor is not needed. If the constructor is invoked like a function, `this` would be `window`.

Comment: If nothing was bound, most browsers default to `window`: https://i.imgur.com/ypyMOhk.png

Comment: Value returned from a constructor is ignored, you can return anything, it doesn't do anything: https://i.imgur.com/LaqOdjp.png